# How to clone existing repos to a group in gitlab

Tags: git, import, export, gitlab

I've a fresh gitlab setup and everything is working perfect. And I've several existing repositories(each has thousands of commits and tens of branches) that I want to import to gitlab. I've a folder structure of bare repos like

> -operators
> --xxxxx.git
> --yyyyy.git
> --zzzzz.git
>
> --offices
> --xxxxx1.git
> --yyyyy2.git
> --zzzzz3.git

and so on

what I want to do is create first level folders as groups and second level folders as projects. Is it possible to do this in gitlab import?

I've checked this https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Export-existing-repositories-to-gitlab but it does not work as I expected. It just creates first level git repos.

Answer (score 2):

On the server, [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) manages itself the layout for storing repositories.

So, the notion of "[groups of repositories](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/groups.html)" (that you find in gitolite, the [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) used by gitlab) has nothing to do with the actual directory organization used to store those same repos.

When gitlab creates a repo, it delegates that creation to gitolite, which will store it in (by default) in `~/repositories`.
(which is why the page "[Export existing repositories to gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Export-existing-repositories-to-gitlab)" mentions `/home/git/repositories`)

Comment: I got what you mean but I cannot import repos under any project group. Is there a way to do this? I don't care where the files are stored. I just want to manage some projects as group.

Comment: @esunar not directly with GitLab: you will have to modify the gitolite.conf if the gitolite-admin repo to declare such group. GitLab offers only a notion of namespace, since 3.1 and 4.0pre.